# Unable to start Java-client 1.5.0 NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, scala, appium, nosuchmethoderror, java-client

I have got a problem with new java-client 1.5.0 and Appium 1.1.0. When I want to run tests, it wrote:

```
*** RUN ABORTED ***
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.<init>           (Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/ErrorCodes;Z)V
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<clinit>(AppiumDriver.java:38)
at po.Driver$.setup(Driver.scala:39)
at src.test.BaseTest.startTestWithLogin(BaseTest.scala:42)
at zzzPokus.NaZkousku$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(NaZkousku.scala:23)
at zzzPokus.NaZkousku$$anonfun$1.apply(NaZkousku.scala:23)
at zzzPokus.NaZkousku$$anonfun$1.apply(NaZkousku.scala:23)
at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfter$class.runTest(BeforeAndAfter.scala:195)
at src.test.BaseTest.runTest(BaseTest.scala:13)
at org.scalatest.FeatureSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FeatureSpecLike.scala:259)
at org.scalatest.FeatureSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FeatureSpecLike.scala:259)
...
```

my Driver.setup method looks like this:

```
def setup {
val caps: DesiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "cz.tipsport.bet")
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android")
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "4.2.2")
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "cz.tipsport.bet.gui.SplashScreenActivity")
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, """I:/testing/Mobil/Android/test/tipsport_test.apk""")
driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), caps)
}
```

That NoSuchMethodError is pointing at Driver line 39 which is:

```
driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), caps)
```

Have you got any idea where could be a problem? Documentation is not much helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I solved it. I found in documentation, that new java-client 1.5.0 depends on selenium 2.42.2 but in my pom.xml was selenium 2.41.0. After upgrading, everything seems to be ok.

Comment: Yes, use both the updated versions. This works. There is a version clash issue. So better use the updated versions.

Answer (score 0):

NoSuchMethodError is usually a result of using different version of a plugin or library than the application was built against.

Comment: Yeah, [it's already stated so in nosuchmethoderror info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/nosuchmethoderror/info).

Comment: Of course its caused by different version of some library (stop working after update from java-client 1.1.0 to 1.5.0) but how can I fix it if I want to use newest version of it?

Comment: If you want to use a different version of some library where other libaries also depend on it then you also must upgrade those. If the API was changed between versions there is no way to make it work. In this case it looks like appium depends on different version of selenium.